# Split Into Lists based on Object, without instanceof

Tags: java, list, oop, object, instanceof

Im going to go straight to the point.

I got 3 classes. Person, Professor and Student. (Persona, Profesor, Alumno).
Both professor and student extends from Person. But Person can also be instantiated, because it's not abstract.

I have 50 persons, randomly generated on a list. It can be any kind, person professor or student.
I want to separate them each into a different list.

At the moment, I did this:

```
for(Persona persona : personas) {
        if(persona instanceof Profesor) {
            profesores.add((Profesor) persona);
        }
        else if(persona instanceof Alumno) {
            alumnos.add((Alumno) persona);
        }
        else {
            nuevasPersonas.add(persona);
        }
    }
```

profesores is a list of Professor

alumnos is a list of Students

nuevasPersonas is a list of Persons

Which works perfect. But I was told not to use instanceof, so I don't get used to it.

Any ideas on how to separate them into lists, without the use of instanceof?

Thanks.

Comment: please don't post images of code. post the text itself using proper formatting

Comment: @PatrickParker Fixed!

Comment: Unless there is some sort of tag to indicate the type of the `Persona`; or `isProfesor()`, `isAlumno()` methods; or some means of doing double dispatch, you've got to do this with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use instanceof, why wouldn't you want to get used to it?

Anyway, an alternative could be having a variable type (with getter, but no setter), in Person (=0), and override it to 1 and 2 in Professor and Student.
Then,you would test the variable instead of using instanceof.

Comment: The reason I was thought to why not use instanceof, was because most of the times it can be fixed using polymorphism, which is a better and more cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use getClass().getSimpleName() as below:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<Test1> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
    Test1 o1 = new Test1();
    list.add(o1);
    Test2 o2 = new Test2();
    list.add(o2);
    for (Test1 test : list) {
        System.out.println(test.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
static class Test1{

}
static class Test2 extends Test1{

}
```

in the for loop you can have a if condition as like as below code to do your job:

```
for (Test1 test : list) {
    String className = test.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if(className.equals("Test1")) {
       System.out.println("Test1");
    } else if(className.equals("Test2")) {
       System.out.println("Test2");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

another solution according to overriding methods is:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<Test1> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
    Test1 o1 = new Test1();
    list.add(o1);
    Test2 o2 = new Test2();
    list.add(o2);
    for (Test1 test : list) {
        test.addToMyTypeList();
    }
    for(Test1 test : Test1.list) {
        System.out.println(test.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    for(Test1 test : Test1.list) {
        System.out.println(test.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
static class Test1{
    public static List<Test1> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addToMyTypeList() {
        String className = test.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if(className.equals("Test1")) {
                    Test1.list.add(this);
        }
    }
}
static class Test2 extends Test1{
    public static List<Test1> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addToMyTypeList() {
        String className = test.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if(className.equals("Test2")) {
                    Test2.list.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Same comment as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224143/split-into-lists-based-on-object-without-instanceof#comment91397704_52224315).

Comment: @Turner in that case, the problem changes and I prefer to have an enum of the types I have guaranteed to route their objects to separate lists and in the for loop, I will iterate on the enum keys too. Therefore, when the question changes, there is no need to use the same method. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your teacher wants you to create an [overriden method](https://crunchify.com/java-method-overriding-examples-and-concepts-overriding-rules/) which answers the question `isStudent` or `isProfessor`?

However, since this gives us no extra information that is not already available via the `instanceof` operator, this is a contrived example where adding these redundant methods is not really a great design decision. Unfortunately in beginner classes you will sometimes encounter such contrived examples which are overly simplified for the purpose of teaching a particular language concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload an "add" method with each of the object types - something like the following code.

The main method just adds instances of three different Objects to the ObjectSplitter class - it separates them out in to different Collections

```
public class ObjectSplitter {

public static void main(String ... args){

    ObjectSplitter d = new ObjectSplitter();
    d.addToCollection(new Object1());
    d.addToCollection(new Object1());
    d.addToCollection(new Object2());
    d.addToCollection(new Object1());
    d.addToCollection(new Object1());
    d.addToCollection(new Object1());
    d.addToCollection(new Object2());
    d.addToCollection(new Object3());
    d.addToCollection(new Object1());

    System.out.println("Num Ob1s : " + d.getOb1sSize());
    System.out.println("Num Ob2s : " + d.getOb2sSize());
    System.out.println("Num Ob3s : " + d.getOb3sSize());

}

private List<Object1> ob1s = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Object2> ob2s = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Object3> ob3s = new ArrayList<>();

void addToCollection(Object1 o){
    ob1s.add(o);
}

void addToCollection(Object2 o){
    ob2s.add(o);
}

void addToCollection(Object3 o){
    ob3s.add(o);
}

int getOb1sSize(){
    return ob1s.size();
}

int getOb2sSize(){
    return ob2s.size();
}

int getOb3sSize(){
    return ob3s.size();
}

static class Object1 {

}


static class Object2 extends Object1 {

}

static class Object3 extends Object2 {

}
```

}